# Is there a name for this property of XOR?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I noticed that XOR ($\oplus$) has a somewhat "mutualistic" property:

$\left(\left(A \oplus B\right)\iff C\right) \iff \left(A \iff \left(B \oplus C\right)\right)$

This can be easily checked via a truth table.

Saying that if C is equivalent with the value of A XOR B, then also A is equivalent with the value of B XOR C (and B is equivalent with the value of A XOR C).

Is there a name for this property?

I first thought it might be derived from the associative property, but then I checked that AND and OR (which have the associative property too) don't have this property.

Comment: [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation is essentially that $B\oplus(A\oplus B)\iff A$; this follows from the fact that $\oplus$ is commutative and satisfies $X\oplus X=\bot$ for all $X$, where $\bot$ is **FALSE**. It’s the exact analogue of the fact that if $\mathbin\triangle$ is symmetric difference, then $B\mathbin\triangle(A\mathbin\triangle B)=A$, which follows from the commutativity of $\mathbin\triangle$ and the fact that $X\mathbin\triangle X=\varnothing$ for all $X$.

Here’s a slightly different way to look at it. For fixed $A$ (of the appropriate kind) the maps $X\mapsto A\oplus X$ and $X\mapsto A\mathbin\triangle X$ are involutions: apply either map twice, and you get back the original input. That is, $A\oplus(A\oplus X)=X$, and $A\mathbin\triangle(A\mathbin\triangle X)=X$. Your observation follows from the fact that this is true for all $A$ and the commutativity of $\oplus$.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, one usually says that $\;\oplus\;$ and $\;\iff\;$ are *mutually associative*.

And since one is the negation of the other, in other words
$$
A \oplus B \;\iff\; \lnot (A \iff B)
$$
therefore I much prefer to use the symbols $\;\not\equiv\;$ and $\;\equiv\;$ instead: that makes the relationship between these two symbols clearly visible.

Then one can, for example, define the symmetric difference of sets $\;S\;$ and $\;T\;$ as
$$
x \in S \triangle T \;\equiv\; x \in S \not\equiv x \in T
$$
for every $\;x\;$, without the need for any parentheses because of the mutual associativity of $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\not\equiv\;$.